# How to track page reloads in Angular application

Tags: angular

I have some code that I use to try to track page reloads. The only way out, I try to do it with `sessionStorage`. The purpose of the task is as follows: if we open the application in Angular, nothing happens to us, and when we reload the page the variable `isPageReloaded` appeared in `sessionStorage`. And when we close the browser window or the browser itself, this variable must be removed from `sessionStorage`. So if we have a page reload, I want to show some elements in the html template using the `isPageReloaded` variable. How to turn this code into the essence of my task?

```
isPageReloaded: any;

constructor(){
   if(sessionStorage.getItem('refreshCount') !== null){
   this.isPageReloaded = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('refreshCount') as string);
   } else {
     sessionStorage.setItem('refreshCount', JSON.stringify(0));
   }
}

@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
onPageRefresh() {
  this.isPageReloaded++;
  sessionStorage.setItem('refreshCount', this.isPageReloaded);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Routing?

Comment: @schlonzo, no, i don't have routing. This applies to reloading the page

Comment: Your application can't tell the difference between a refresh and the browser being closed. I think it may help if you explain why you're trying to achieve this as there may be something functionally similar that can achieve the result you're after.

Comment: @schlonzo, i am using the routing, i made a mistake. The answer below it almost what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator object that is supported by most browsers

```
//check for Navigation Timing API support
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
console.info(performance.navigation.type);
if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
  console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's almost what I wanted. The fact is that I made a mistake and in fact I still use routing between components and as soon as I go to the components I need, it says that my page is already reloaded. Can you please help that this logic was not at routing, and was already at reload? Thank you very much)))